CICFlowmeter tcpdump Permission denied
Im trying to install TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter from this CICFlowmeter
my server is Ubuntu, my steps was
root@testbed-ml-node:~# git clone https://github.com/iPAS/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter.git
root@testbed-ml-node:~# cd TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/
root@testbed-ml-node:~/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter# nano try_me.sh

I edit the file try_me.sh
capture_interface_pcap.sh wlan0 pcap
Then To Fix the Permission Denied Problem, add the following line into file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump:
/usr/sbin/tcpdump {
  #...
  # for -z
  /**/* ixr,      
  # <-- add me!
  #...
}

Also, To Fix java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError Problem
sudo apt install libpcap-dev

Then i run the script
root@testbed-ml-node:~/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter# ./try_me.sh 

i Get error
root@testbed-ml-node:~/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter# sudo ./try_me.sh
tcpdump: listening on enp1s0f0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
tcpdump: pcap/2024-08-01-19:46:04.pcap: Permission denied
compress_savefile: execlp(/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/convert_pcap_csv.sh, pcap/2024-08-01-19:45:04.pcap) failed: Permission denied
=== Capturer is being cancled ===
=== Wait the converter finished for 3 seconds...

=== Convert left PCAP files if any
=== pcap/2024-08-01-19:45:04.pcap is left
>>> Script dir: /root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter
+++ CICFlowMeter PCAP-to-CSV Converter +++
    Input file: pcap/2024-08-01-19:45:04.pcap
    Output dir: /root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/csv
run at:   /root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter
app at:   /root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0
SAVED:    /root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter
APP_HOME: /root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0
CLASSPATH: /root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/CICFlowMeter-4.0.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/commons-lang3-3.6.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/commons-math3-3.5.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/guava-23.6-jre.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/java-cup-0.11a.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/jfreechart-1.5.0.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/jnetpcap-1.4.r1425-1g.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/junit-4.12.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/log4j-api-2.11.0.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/log4j-core-2.11.0.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/tika-core-1.17.jar:/root/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter/CICFlowMeters/CICFlowMeter-4.0/lib/weka-stable-3.6.14.jar
cic.cs.unb.ca.ifm.CICFlowMeter
cic.cs.unb.ca.ifm.CICFlowMeter CICFlowMeter-V3 found: 1 Files.
cic.cs.unb.ca.jnetpcap.PacketReader Error while opening file for capture: truncated dump file; tried to read 4 file header bytes, only got 0
+++ Remove pcap/2024-08-01-19:45:04.pcap
+++ Finish the conversion

=== Clean stuff up

root@testbed-ml-node:~/TCPDUMP_and_CICFlowMeter# client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset

Why i still get Permission denied, your advice is highly appreciated Thanks in advance
